# Spring MVC, Ajax and Same Origin Policy

Tags: java, ajax, spring-mvc, cors, same-origin-policy

What is the best way to overcome Same Origin Policy in Ajax calls with spring MVC Rest service? Is it adding header values or using JSONP?

How to Map a request with both RequestParam and PathVariable in Spring Mvc REST?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getstudent/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)    
public @ResponseBody Student getStudent(@PathVariable String userId, @RequestParam("callback") String callback) {
    StudentRegister studentRegister = new StudentRegister();
    return studentRegister.getStudent(userId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the `Origin` header is allowed. If yes, add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to the response:

```
@RequestMapping("xhr")    
@ResponseBody
public Object xhr(@RequestHeader("Origin") String origin, HttpServletResponse response) {
    if (LIST_OF_AUTHORIZED_ORIGINS.contains(origin)) {
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
    }
    return toJson();
}
```

Comment: Is it the best practice?

Comment: How to Map a request with both RequestParam and PathVariable in Spring Mvc REST?